# Flask - not responding to a GET request properly?

Tags: html, forms, flask

I am trying to have a download button on a page that will start a download of a file when it is clicked. Using flask as my framework. I'm trying to start the download when the button is clicked and sends a GET request, but nothing is happening. In my console I am just getting `"127.0.0.1 - - [04/Feb/2014 00:10:57] "GET /CpFTHHpsJ/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -"`, which is the same output I get when the page is loaded.

My **HTML** form looks like:

```
<form method="get" action="">
<input type="submit" value="DOWNLOAD">
</form>
```

My **python** for rendering the download page and sending the file:

```
@app.route('/<new_folder_name>/', subdomain='f', methods=['GET'])
def uploaded_file(new_folder_name):
    new_folder_path = os.path.join(app.config['FILE_FOLDER'], new_folder_name)
    filename = subfolder_fetch(new_folder_path)
    return render_template("download.html", filename=filename, new_folder_path=new_folder_path)
    if request.method == "GET":
        send_from_directory(new_folder_path, filename, as_attachment=True)
```

Sorry if this is stupid, I'm a beginner with both HTML forms and web programming. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you're rendering and returning `download.html` before you call `send_from_directory`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You never actually `return` your `send_from_directory`, so the file will never be returned to the end user.
2. You will never get to the code, regardless, because you `return render_template` before you get to your test method.
3. There is no way for you to distinguish a page load from a "Download" click with the code you have there.

#### How to fix #3

- Add a `name` to the Download link form:

  ```
  <input type="submit" name="action" value="Download">
  ```

  and test for its existence in your controller:

  ```
  if "action" in request.args:
      # Download
  else:
      # Show page
  ```
- Alternately, use a link pointing at a separate controller:

  ```
  @app.route('/<folder>/download')
  def download_file(folder):
      # etc.
  ```

  and in your template create a link and style it like a button:

  ```
  <a href="{{ url_for('download_file', folder=folder) }}" class="download">Download Now</a>
  ```